# PHP DateTime diff weird result

Tags: php, datetime

I am having a weird problem with PHP's DateTime diff method. I've been using DateTime methods for some while now and thought I've got the hang of it, but this problem amazes me.

I am using the diff method to determine the number of months/days between two dates.
Today, I used the following code:

```
$start = new DateTime('2012-03-01');
$end = new DateTime('2012-03-31');

$period = $start->diff($end);

var_dump($period);
```

Which produced the following output:

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 1 // Shouldn't this be 0?
  public 'd' => int 1 // And where does this come from? Would expect 30.
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 30
```

As my comment above says, where the hell does the 1m1d come from (I would expect 0m30d). I can't for the life of me figure out where it gets this value from. I also tried putting the midnight timestamp `00:00:00` behind both dates to make sure it wasn't a time thing, but that made no difference to the output.

Can anybody explain this outcome to me?
This problem occurs on my Debian development server, running PHP 5.3.3 with Xdebug 2.1.1 and Suhosin 0.9.32.1 installation.

**Update**

Reproduced this problem on my production server, which is on CentOS 6.0 with "raw" PHP 5.3.8 without any extensions/patches.

**Update 2**

I managed to find a "workaround" (only working at this moment in time). If I change the absolute dates to:

```
$start = new DateTime('first day of next month');
$end = new DateTime('last day of next month');
```

It does give 0m30d as output. Still, I'm stumped by the above, so if anyone has a clue about that, please let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations, you have just discovered DST! If you check with the DST switchover for your timezone, you will see that $start is actually getting Feb-29, and $end getting Mar-30. (2-3) = 1 (therefore, m=1), and (29-30) = 1 (therefore, d=1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly the problem. I adjusted my code to use `new DateTime('2012-03-01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));` and `new DateTime('2012-03-31', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));` instead, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same result as you and my result is actually ok...

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(30)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(30)
}
```

Its not normal to get 1 month cause there ISNT even a month yet between the two dates, 1 month would be for

```
$start = new DateTime('2012-03-01');
$end = new DateTime('2012-04-01');
```

What i see here is you maybe got -1 day and 1 month instead of 30 days and you thought you saw 1 day 1 month, or the code you got is not what you pasted here...

Can you enlighten us?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just figured it should be 0m30d indeed, so updated my question accordingly. The code is **exactly** as pasted above.

Comment: Then maybe upgrading will help, i'm at 5.3.6 with xdebug 2.1.0

Comment: I just tested this code on my production server, which is on different OS and PHP 5.3.8, it produces the exact same output, weird stuff :\

Comment: Something is deadly wrong with your setup then, even on the production server. Cause you get illogical results (which would have been found by automated tests months ago) and my results get out right.... My guess is that something is interfering with your code, memory or output... But only god knows what for now...

Comment: I just had a flash, can you dump de dates after creating them? Maybe its a format error when parsing, cause the diff shouldnt be hard to calculate...

Comment: Dumping the dates after creation gives: `object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2012-03-01 00:00:00'
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin'` for the first date and for the second: `object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2012-03-31 00:00:00'
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin'`. Seems valid.

Comment: Indeed, i'm stumped too, maybe Berlin doesn't calculate dates the same way north americans do :P Good luck, can't help you more than that

Answer (score 0):

The comments on [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) page (PHP manual) seem to suggest that the function can be quite buggy on certain platforms or with certain ranges of input.

This may well be the cause of your problem.